# Proving the existence of a sequence such that

Tags: analysis, number-theory

I am trying to prove that there exists a sequence, for example:

$$ f(n) = n! $$

(or we can select any sequence we need to prove the existence of just one), with the following property:

edit:

for all $i,j \in \mathbb N$ with $i$ is $j$ distinct:

there exists a $z \in \mathbb N$ so that ($z$ is dependent on $i,j$):

$$f(i) + z \ is \ prime$$ 
$$f(j) + z \ is \ not \ prime$$
$$ or \ vice \ versa$$

Here naturally our $z$ can be written in terms of $f(i) \ and \ f(j)$.
For example we can say (using the above sequence):

Take the next prime $p$ after $(f(j) = j!)$.

Then set our $z$ to $p - j!$
We know that:
$j!+z = j!+(p-j!) = p$ is prime.
However if we use this $z$ we cannot prove that
$i!+z = i!+p-j!$ is not prime.

If we could find a sequence with such a $z$, we are done.

Comment: What you are looking for is impossible the way it is written now.

Comment: Your statement of the desired property is unclear, at least to me. If $i=j$ then the condition can't hold. Also, suppose $i,j,k$ are distinct. For $(i,j)$, suppose $i$ produces the prime, then for $(j,k)$ it must be the case that $k$ produces the prime. What then for $(i,k)$? They both produce a prime, impossible if your condition is to hold.

Comment: There's also a difficult-to-interpret equivocation about the dependencies of the variables.  First you write "there exists a $z\in\mathbb N$ so that for all $i,j\in\mathbb N$...", which clearly states that $z$ may not depend on $i,j$, but then you say "naturally our $z$ can be written in terms of $f(i)$ and $f(j)$", which seems to say almost the opposite.

Comment: thank you for the comments I have edited the question